# Splitting down a data frame column from ib_insync

Tags: ib-api

I am reasonably new to python and am struggling to breakdown the below.

Stock(conId=3691937, symbol='AMZN', exchange='SMART', primaryExchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='AMZN', tradingClass='NMS')

This is a row in a dataframe with the column header order_contract

how do i break this down into seperate columns with headers conId , symbol , exchange , primaryExchange , currency , localSymbol , tradingClass

and the rows 3691937 , AMZN , SMART , NASDAQ , USD , AMZN , NMS

Sorry this isnt a well formatted question i am new to stackoverflow. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should show what you've tried when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ib_insync contract object is what you showed, this should suffice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x.__dict__ for x in df.order_contract])
```